# Rename .txt files to first line in file?

Tags: python, file-rename

I've got a lot of .txt files with names starting with "read" that I want to rename. I want them to be named with the first line in the file. I'm a really lousy programmer, but I've given it a go and now I'm stuck.

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("."):
   if filename.startswith("read"):
      for line in filename:
        os.rename(filename, line)
```

At the moment the script does nothing and even if it worked I'm pretty sure the files wouldn't keep their extensions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to open the file to get the first line from it. `for line in filename` is a for-loop that iterates over the filename, not the contents of the file, since you didn't open the actual file.

Also a for-loop is intended to iterate over all of the file, and you only want the first line.

Finally, a line from a text file includes the end-of-line character (`'\n'`) so you need to `.strip()` that out.

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("."):
   if filename.startswith("read"):
      with open(filename) as openfile:
        firstline = openfile.readline()
      os.rename(filename, firstline.strip())
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you it kinda works. The problem with loss of file extension remains. A new problem now is with illegal characters in the filename(mostly " and :) any easy way to strip them out?

Answer (score 0):

What if you replaced your inner loop with something like:

```
if not filename.startswith("read"): continue
base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    newname = infile.next().rstrip()
newname += ext
os.rename(filename, newname)
```