# Rename .txt files to values separated by comma at first line in file?

Tags: python, csv, file-rename

Following this thread: [Rename .txt files to first line in file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729484/rename-txt-files-to-first-line-in-file/18729691)
I came up with this code:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("."):
   if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
   with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        newname = infile.next().rstrip()
   newname += ext
   os.rename(filename, newname)
```

This works well, but what I really need is to name the file not after the entire first line, but after string located between commas. The first line has various values separated by commas (csv), and I need to rename the file with the second value, that is, the string of text that appears between the second and third commas.

I have found a csv module, but I don't know if it helps or how to use it. I found that I could import it this way: `import unicodecsv as csv` to avoid strange character problems.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ummm

```
newname = infile.next().rstrip().split(",")[2]
```

maybe? not sure its hard to tell from the question

Comment: thanks for quick answer, but it gives me this `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Answer (score 0):

tanks to @Joran Beasley it is working perfectly well, the code now is:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("."):
   if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
   with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        newname = infile.next().rstrip().split(",")[1]
   newname += ""
   os.rename(filename, newname)
```

Comment: hmmm that makes me think you actually meant between the first and second comma,  and you accidentally said 2nd and 3rd comma?